# Three Network Addresses from IP Address and Subnet Constraints

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

Consider a router that interconnects three subnets: Subnet 1, Subnet 2, and Subnet 3. Suppose all of the interfaces in each of these three subnets are required to have the prefix 138.157.45/24. Also,suppose that Subnet 1 is required to support up to 111 interfaces, and Subnets 2 and 3 are each required to port up to 63 interfaces. Provide three network addresses (of the form a.b.c.d/x) that satisfy these constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Network addresses:

- Subnet 1: 138.157.45.0/25 (128 addresses)
- Subnet 2: 138.157.45.128/26 (64 addresses)
- Subnet 3: 138.157.45.192/26 (64 addresses)

Note that in practice 2 of all possible address in a subnet are not assigned to any interface. These are:

- Broadcast address, like x.x.x.255/24
- Network address, like x.x.x.0/24